# Contact Form not Validating

Tags: php, html, css

Anyone shed any light on why the following:

```
<form id="" method="post" action="" />
                    <input type="text" name="" title="" tabindex="10" class="" />
                    <input type="password" name="" title="" tabindex="20" class="password" />
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit" value="" />
                </form>
```

Gets this error form W3C:

```
Line 101, Column 11: end tag for element "form" which is not open

                </form>
```

When I leave the end tag of each line as '>' as opposed to '/>' I get further issues. Can some assist me in re-dong this form so that it validates.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the slash at the end of `<form id="client_login_form" method="post" action="" />`. That closes the tag immediately like in `<br />`.

Comment: Hi, did that and now I have 3 errors as per this: ine 98, Column 97: document type does not allow element "input" here; missing one of "p", "h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6", "div", "pre", "address", "fieldset", "ins", "del" start-tag

…text" name="login_user_name" title="Username" tabindex="10" class="username" />

Comment: @Bill Johnson: "missing one of" means exactly what it reads. The reason the validator complains is that certain tags must be children of certain other tags. W3C has all the details. Take some time, read the validator output carefully. And if you still can't write valid (X)HTML, there are plenty of good howtos in the net ...

Comment: Okay, can you please give me some indication of what I should be changing here to include the correct tags? thanks

Comment: The validator gave you indication: document type does not allow element "input" here; missing one of "p". So wrap your inputs in p tags, validate again and see what it says!

Comment: Passed with <p></p> on all 3 rows...thank you for your help! appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Your opening form tag ends with
    />
Closing itself.

Change it to

```
<form id="client_login_form" method="post" action="">
```